# Unable to run a model using HuggingFace Inference Endpoints

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am able to make successful requests using the free endpoint, but when using Inference Endpoints, I get 404 response. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```py
mode = 'paid'                                              # works if 'free'
model_id = "sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN}"}

if mode == 'free':
    # This works
    api_url = f"https://api-inference.huggingface.co/pipeline/feature-extraction/{model_id}"
else:
    api_url = f"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud/{model_id}"

def get_embeddings(texts):
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json={"inputs": texts, "options":{"wait_for_model":True}})
```

In the web UI, the endpoint is shown as running and I can test it there no problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welp, not found mean not found... Are you 100% sure the URL is correct?

Comment: @doneforaiur I copied the url using the provided copy button and paste it into the code. I did it again just in case...

Comment: But you ommited the part between `https://` and `.us ...` right?

Comment: @doneforaiur No, this part is part of the copied URL...

Comment: That's the problem. It has to be something like this: `https://oncm9ojdmjwesag2.eu-west-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud` and there should be `model_id` and the end of it but I might be wrong about the second part.

Comment: @doneforaiur How is it not like this in my code? `api_url = f"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud/{model_id}"`

Comment: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is clearly not a bunch of random characters and the actual URL is censored for security purposes.

Comment: @doneforaiur I replaced those characters by x's for the question.

Comment: I specifically asked that... Then I think it's the `/{model_id}` part of the URL that gives problem. Could you try removing it?

Comment: @doneforaiur Sorry for the misunderstanding. Without the `model_id`, I get the 400 response and the error message in the log: `ERROR | list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Okay, we are getting closer! That is propably because `texts` is a list which should be a `str`?

Comment: @doneforaiur No, this model produces embeddings for multiple strings. As the question states, it works when using the free endpoint.

Comment: Yes, right! Altough the example tab at Hugging Face says it should be like this; ```{
 "inputs": {
  "source_sentence": "That is a happy person",
  "sentences": [
   "That is a happy dog",
   "That is a very happy person",
   "Today is a sunny day"
  ]
 },
}``` for `all-MiniLM-L6-v2`. Interesting, I'll do some more digging.

Comment: @doneforaiur Indeed, the following works and returns similarities: `curl https://gm8xjdoa1gmu9gqr.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud -X POST -d '{"inputs": {"source_sentence": "That is a happy person", "sentences": ["That is a happy dog", "That is a very happy person", "Today is a sunny day"]}}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer hf_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`, but I need to get the embeddings.

Comment: You should delete your token. :^) Could you update your Python request and see if that works? If that doesn't work, I'm really lost.

Comment: For now, I want to get a curl request that returns embeddings. Then I can translate it into Python. So, I am trying `curl https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.aws.endpoints.huggingface.cloud -X POST -d '{"inputs": ["That is a happ is a sunny day"]}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'` and get the error: `{"error":"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"}`

Comment: It does return similarities. That sounds to me that it was deployed to do that? Can you check `task` section while deploying the model [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/inference-endpoints) (there's a screenshot where you can select the task type)? Since we can't interract with the actual API code...

Comment: Happy to hear that! It was a long ride lol.

Comment: @doneforaiur A little unrelated, but do you happen to know whether I'd have to pay for another endpoint for each task and model that I need to use?

Comment: I've added an answer, if you notice any mistakes please let me know! For your last comment: sadly I don't know. :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments;

1. The URL doesn't have a `/{model_id}` endpoint.
2. The `task` section should be filled correctly according to your needs.

After removing the `/{model_id}`, we faced a `400, list indices must be integers or slices, not str` message. Which was caused by the faulty task. Instead of getting the embeddings, it was trying to get the similarities between strings in a list. After changing the task to embeddings, the model successfully generated embeddings from a single string. For a detailed tutorial that covers the deployment process, please see [Getting Started with Hugging Face Inference Endpoints](https://huggingface.co/blog/inference-endpoints) .